# Is there any connection between the Samaritan woman's five husbands and the rich man's five brothers?

Tags: jesus, temple, samaritans, jews

> (for I have five brothers) to warn them so that they don't come into this place of torment.' Luke 16:28 NET

> for you have had five husbands, and the man you are living with now is not your husband. This you said truthfully!" John 4:18 NET

In the parable of the rich man and Lazarus the phrase "my father's house" (Luke 16:27 NET) is used and in the story of the Samaritan woman the verse: "Our fathers worshiped on this mountain, and you people say that the place where people must worship is in Jerusalem."  John  4:20 NET

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting and thought-provoking question.  The Bible is full of imagery and parallelism, and it would show abject ignorance of its depth to boldly declare that there could be no connection between the passages cited, seeing as they both do have similarities in their language.

However, to establish that they are indeed connected, one must be able to explain the meanings of their similar wordings.

Of what significance, to Jesus or to us, should the numbers five or six have?

What relationship exists between the two "fathers" mentioned?

In the latter case, the woman's mention of "our fathers" clearly is to human parentage, and "my father's house" is also to human parentage--yet both passages *also* reference God as our Father (see below).

> Then he said, I pray thee therefore, **father,** that thou wouldest send
> him to my **father's house**: (Luke 16:27, KJV)
>
> <sup>20</sup> **Our fathers** worshipped in this mountain; and ye say,
> that in Jerusalem is the place where men ought to worship.
> <sup>21</sup> Jesus saith unto her, Woman, believe me, the hour
> cometh, when ye shall neither in this mountain, nor yet at Jerusalem,
> worship **the Father.** (John 4:20-21, KJV)

Returning to the significance of the five husbands or five brothers--in each case, the sixth person represents the one addressed: the man who is not her husband applies to her *now*; and the one who has five brothers is the sixth in the family.

The number six is of interest, in my opinion, because it corresponds to the number of days given to mankind to work in a week--the seventh day being reserved for God.  In a sense, each of the weekdays represents a millennial epoch of earth's history, and the seventh is "the Lord's day"--the day when Jesus returns to hand out his rewards to the faithful and punishments to the wicked.

Each of these epochs, or generations, has its own opportunity for salvation.  In the allegory of the rich man and Lazarus, the truth was presented that those who have closed their minds would not reopen them even if one rose from the dead and came to speak with them.  This is crucial information.  Jesus is teaching that each one must accept the truth individually, independent of the others.

It is also of interest that in prophecy, a woman represents a church.  The bridegroom (husband) represents God, who comes to receive His bride.  Having other husbands represents unfaithfulness (consider the illustration of Aholah and Aholibah in Ezekiel 23).

Does living with a man who was *not* her husband imply that she were more open to accepting God as her true Lord and Master?  The lessons from this story are boundless.

Answer (score 0):

This will not answer the question except to show that "five" is not really a connection between the two incidents.

- Matt 25:2 - five wise and five foolish virgins
- Matt 25:16, 20 - five talents
- Mark 8:19 - five loaves and five thousand people. See also Matt 16:9, Luke 9:16
- Luke 1:24 - five months
- Luke 12:6 - five sparrows sold for a denarius
- Luke 12:52 - five in one family
- Luke 14:19 - five yoke of oxen
- Luke 19:18 - five minas
- Luke 19:19 - five cities
- John 5:2 - five colonnades
- Acts 24:1 - five days later
- 1 Cor 14:19 - five intelligible words
- 2 Cor 11:24 - five times Paul receives 39 lashes
- Rev 9:5 - five months

These may or may not allude to the many "fives" in the OT such as Ex 26:3, Num 7:17, 29, 23, 71, 77, 1 Kings 7:49, 2 Chron 4:6, etc.

Thus, all that can be said about the number "five" in the NT is that it was a popular number in Jesus' parables.